# How to insert html code as a value for <textarea>?

Tags: html

I have a page where users can copy content of `<textarea>`. And its content is code to embed on their websites. Should I replace html brackets `<` and `>` with  `&lt;` and `&;gt` or `<`, `>` are fine?

```
<textarea>
  <script src="example.com" async></script>
  <div class="kr-container"></div>
</textarea>
```

Comment: If you want it to function as HTML then you need to leave the brackets. If you're only interested in plain text, then you should replace them to avoid misinterpreting them as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use character codes instead if you want users to copy and paste code from the textarea

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&lt;` as well as `<`. Both are correct. You can try it on http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro